# Fetching last n characters of string in ksh

Tags: linux, string, shell, solaris, ksh

Let say i have a variable `name` holding some string value

To fetch last n characters, in bash we write :

```
$ echo "${name: -n}"
```

what is the equivalent way in `ksh`, i have seen `sed` and `awk` methods but what i am looking for is one line or piping solution similar to `bash` to extract last characters

These are errors and efforts so far :

```
AB12 $ name="123456"

AB12 $ echo ${name:(-3)}
ksh: ${name:(-3)}: bad substitution

AB12 $ echo${name:0:-3}
ksh: echo${name:0:-3}: bad substitution

AB12 $ print ${name%?}
12345

AB12 $  echo "some string" | tail -c -1
tail: cannot open input

AB12 $ echo -n "my string discard"| tail -c -1
tail: cannot open input

AB12 $ echo "foo"| cut -c 1-2
fo

AB12 $ echo "foo"| cut -c -2
fo

AB12 $ echo $name
123456

AB12 $ echo "${name: -3}"
ksh: "${name: -3}": bad substitution
```

I am on Solaris currently - *if this helps*!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this, say n=2 (we will use 2 question marks in the nested expansion):

```
$ var="this is my var"
$ echo "${var#${var%??}}"
ar
```

**Explanation**

It is a nested expansion.

The expansion `${var%%??}` is embedded in the expansion `${var# }`.
 The `${var#string}` expansion will cut off anything from the beginning of the variable which matches 'string'. So we are saying in this instance, removing anything from the beginning of the variable which matches `${var%%??}`.

On its own, `${var%%??}` matches "this is my v" for the variable in the example, as the`%%` expansion matches the longest possible match at the end of the variable. In this case, two regexp ?'s.

Comment: dint understood this part => `var#${var%??}` ?? :)

Comment: It is a nested expansion. The expansion ${var%%??} is embedded in the expansion ${var# }.

The ${var#string} expansion will cut off anything from the beginning of the variable which matches 'string'. So we are saying in this instance, removing anything from the beginning of the variable which matches ${var%%??}. On its own, ${var%%??} matches "this is my v" for the variable in the example, as the %% expansion matches the longest possible match at the end of the variable. In this case, two regexp ?'s. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is correct example for getting last few string chars for Korn Shell Script. Thanks much :) Ell

Answer (score 2):

Your cut is looking good, just get the correct offset.

```
#!/bin/ksh
var="This is a string"
n=2
(( offset =  ${#var} - $n + 1 ))
echo ${var} | cut -c ${offset}-
```

or as a oneliner

```
echo ${var} | cut -c $(expr  ${#var} - $n + 1 )-
```

Answer (score 1):

There's already an accepted answer, but here's an alternative method, using the `ksh` notion of justified viariables:

```
var="This is a test"
typeset -R4 foo
foo="${var}"
echo "${foo}"
```

The right (and left) justification attributes result in truncation if the length is exceeded, or padding if the assigned value is too short.